# Can i query the database in the middle of a 'map' closure with Couchbase Lite?

Tags: swift, couchbase, couchbase-lite

In Couchbase Lite, is this permissible/encouraged or will it cause race conditions / any other problems?

```
let view = database.viewNamed("myView")
view.setMapBlock({ properties, emit in
  database.existingDocument(withID: properties["some_foreign_key"])
```

Basically i'm trying to create a view which is the equivalent of an SQL 'left inner join'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not permitted.  Map functions must be pure, as in given the same set of inputs they will always produce the same outputs.  No external state may be referenced.